# RStudio on Mac OS X El Capitan: Package "Rsymphony" - image not found

Tags: r

RStudio on Mac OS X El Capitan: cannot install the package `Rsymphony`,for the reason *"Reason: image not found"*.

```
library("Rsymphony")
```

> 无法载入共享目标对象‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rsymph‌​ony/libs/Rsymphony.so’：:
>   dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rsymphony/‌​libs/Rsymphony.so,
>   6): Library not loaded:
>   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/lib/libgfortran.2.dylib
>   Referenced from:
>   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rsymphony/libs/Rs‌​ymphony.so
>   Reason: image not found 错误: ‘Rsymphony’程辑包或名字空间载入失败，

Comment: library("Rsymphony") : 
  无法载入共享目标对象‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rsymphony/libs/Rsymphony.so’：:
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rsymphony/libs/Rsymphony.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/lib/libgfortran.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rsymphony/libs/Rsymphony.so
  Reason: image not found
错误: ‘Rsymphony’程辑包或名字空间载入失败，

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing `gcc`, i'm almost sure libgfortran ships with it.

I would suggest installing homebrew (http://brew.sh), then use `brew install gcc`.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you are missing:

> Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/lib/libgfortran.2.dylib

Apparently, your installation is incomplete.

Installation errors are off-topic for this web site.